# What program will convert video frames to jpegs?

Tags: video, images

I have a video file, I would like to convert all the frames in the video (every single one) to an image file. How do I do that?

I tried using VLC for this purpose, but it bugged out on me, sadly.

Edit: I was asked about the video file: it's an mp4 file recorded from a Samsung Galaxy S5.

The codec is:
H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0

Comment: what type of video file?

Comment: It's a mobile phone video taken from a nexus 4. But really that's not that important, because there are tons of tools for converting one kind of video file into another.

Comment: Could you add information about what format the video is in (m4v, mov, etc) and what operating system this tool needs to run on?

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend

#### [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

for this (**free**, **open source**, **cross-platform**).

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -qscale:v 2 output_%03d.jpg
```

Will create one `output_<framenumber>.jpg` JPEG image (with quality `2`) for every frame in `input.mp4`.

See [How do I encode movie to single pictures?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-movie-to-single-pictures_003f) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Screenshot Of Free Video To JPG Converter Tool From Free Studio]

[Free Studio](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm#.VUxGuJyJi71) features a tool called [Free Video To JPG Converter](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-to-JPG-Converter.htm) *(which you can alternatively download as a stand-alone tool)*. This tool can create a sequence of JPEGs from videos in various formats. Free Studio is compatible with Windows XP *(SP3 required)*, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

To Use Free Video To JPG Converter just browse for *(or drag-and-drop)* a video file, enter your settings *(eg: extract every frame)*, choose where to save, and click the convert button.

Be aware that this program, like all programs made by this company *(DVDVideoSoft)* like to call home.

Answer (score -1):

### [Free Video to JPG Converter](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-to-JPG-Converter.htm) <sub>should do the job</sub>

[image: Main window]

1. Select the video(s) which you want to convert - you can choose as many as you want. Supported file formats:
   [image: Supported file formats]
2. Choose whether you want to... (this setting applies to all videos in the queue, you can't specify this per video - unless you convert every video one-by-one)

   - extract every *x* frames
   - extract a frame every *x* seconds
   - extract a total of *x* frames from the video(s)
   - extract every frame
3. Select the output directory
4. Click "Convert"

The files will be saved in the `.jpg` format (as the name of the program suggests).

---

Here's a screenshot of the settings:
[image: Settings]

---

*This program is also included in the [Free Studio](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm) package (in the "Convert" category) by the same manufacturer (DVDVideoSoft). If you want a set of multimedia-programs, I'd advise you to install Free Studio. Otherwise, if you only need to convert video's to images, just install Free Video to JPG Converter.*

Comment: Could the person who downvoted my answer - for a still unknown reason - please elaborate why (s)he downvoted (the old version of my) answer, and reconsider the downvote?